# Look through entries of a string list, attempt with each entry to see if there's a match with the target which should turn a bool to true

Tags: c#, list, foreach, boolean

So this is for a game where I'm trying to check for specific status effects on a target.

I have a list with Strings of specific status effects:

```
List<string> StatusList = new List<string>
            { "Status1",
            "Status2",
            "Status3",};
```

The game then has an API which will check the target for a status effect.
I want it to crosscheck with the list to see if there's any match in the list - i.e. the whole list should not need to match, only a single entry matching should be sufficient to return a true.
This is the bool that checks it.

```
bool HasStatus(string StatusName, string Unit = "target");
```

So I've got the below so far to check in the list, but I'm not entirely sure if that's correct, and then I have no idea how to write the bool above to 'call back' to that?

```
bool StatusTest = API.HasStatus(StatusList.Status, "target");

foreach (string Status in StatusList)
{
    if (API.HasStatus(Status, "target"))
    {
        StatusTest = true;
    }
}
```

The above of course produces an error, so I'm not writing it correctly. Any ideas how one would go about this?

Comment: Could you post the exception that throws your code?

Comment: "The above of course produces an error," why of course? and what is the error message? You have posted only the interface declaration. can you post the actual implementation of the `HasStatus` method?

Comment: In your example you use `StatusList.Status`. Maybe turn the List of strings in an Enum if you want to do that. With an enum you could use a `Switch` instead of a `Foreach` and then for each status you get you can check if it's equal to the target status with `Status.Equals(Unit)`. If it matches, return true, default return false.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check to see if a string exists in a List of strings, you can use the `Contains` method. eg:

```
List<string> StatusList = new List<string>
            { "Status1",
            "Status2",
            "Status3",};

if(StatusList.Contains(someStatusToCheck)) {
   // Do something here
}
```

Also, it looks as though the call to `HasStatus` has an incorrect parameter. `StatusList.Status` will throw an error, because there is no attribute `Status` on a `List<String>` type

Comment: Thanks, however I don't want to check if a specifc status exists in the list - I want to check if any of the status entries in the list matches what's currently on the target.
So it should go through the list, see if there are any (one is enough) matches, then change a bool to true if that's the case.

Comment: Ok. That is the same thing however. So `StatusList.Contains("target")` would produce the same result as going through the StatusList one by one and checking each one against the target. If the target exists in the StatusList, then `StatusList.Contains("target")` would return `true` in the same way as your algorithm, except it is just one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

this function should be the one to comapre the statuses. when you have the target, get the `true` or `false` value by using:

`bool result = StatusTest("example_of_target")`

```
List<string> StatusList = new List<string>
            { "Status1",
            "Status2",
            "Status3",};

bool StatusTest(string target) {
        foreach (string Status in StatusList)
       {
         if (Status == target)
           return true       
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the different suggestions!

In the end in this what solved the issue for me.

```
private bool StatusTest;
```

---

```
List<string> StatusList = new List<string>
            { "Status1",
            "Status2",
            "Status3",
            "Status4",};

                foreach (string Status in StatusList)
                {
                if (API.HasStatus(Status, "target"))
                {
                        StatusTest = true;
                }
                else { StatusTest = false; }
                }
```